# feed through selection for my circuit

Tags: impedance-matching

If I want to use feed through for my circuit, which has a high source impedance(500M ohm), what type of filter should I use?
(if C type is OK for my selection or I should use L-type? (also  I have an op amp with high input impedance in another side of feed through)
does inductor characterize is important if I want to use an L-type filter?

Comment: is it long term average ? delay? antenna effective immunity? low CM impedance is what you need, higher impedance load, no bias current, L is irrelevant, C is critical for response and low Z CM differential mode is what you need  with no R diff. mode) load.. special design specs.  U must define these parameters and frequency spectrum or time slew rate.

Answer (score 1):

For this circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAteHb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I would use a SMT 100Kohm and a SMT 1uF, the 1UF has GND end tied to OpAmp GND pin and OpAmp VDD filter GND end.

Comment: T=500 s  (at least no humm but then no signal)  with that high impedance imbalance the cap DC leakage offset voltage will be high. , I would only consider an active-guard shielded balanced differential amp to reduce CM impedance and null shield capacitance.

Comment: Correct, Tony. The OP gave no accuracy nor speed goals. Just wanted to "filter" out something.